# Clip attribute of canvas tag in WPF

Tags: wpf

Trying to find documentation on what the contents of the following clip attribute means in a WPF Canvas tag:

```
<Canvas ....
  Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0"
  ....
```

If I knew what to search for I would have found it already.  I have tried a number of things in google but I'm clearly not calling it the right name.

My guess is:

```
F1                      no idea
M 0.0L                  move to 0,0
76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0  "draw" to 76,0 76,76 0,76 0,0 in turn
```

An explanation of F1 (assuming my guess is correct for the rest) would be nice, but better, a link to some documentation for it.

I have looked at the Geometry class, but don't see any F1 etc on there.

As an extra question, there is also Path tag with:

```
F1 M 22,19L 24,19L 24,57L 22,57L 22,19 Z M 26,57L 26,19L 54,19L 54,57L 26,57 Z M 48.0754,44.4314L 45.626,41.0237C 45.5021,40.8563 45.3454,40.7372 45.1559,40.6665C 44.9665,40.5959 44.778,40.5805 44.5905,40.6204L 44.2039,40.793L 42.6702,41.9363L 42.2196,42.1419C 41.993,42.1901 41.771,42.177 41.5538,42.1025C 41.3366,42.0281 41.1474,41.8799 40.986,41.6579L 36.8403,35.8777L 36.6362,35.4042C 36.5872,35.1734 36.6012,34.9454 36.6782,34.7201C 36.7552,34.4948 36.8951,34.3068 37.0978,34.156L 38.6316,33.0129C 38.8011,32.8884 38.9194,32.7302 38.9863,32.5383C 39.0531,32.3464 39.0654,32.1506 39.0229,31.9507L 38.8496,31.5611L 36.3977,28.1571C 36.2755,27.9872 36.1206,27.8666 35.9332,27.7955C 35.7458,27.7245 35.5563,27.7093 35.3647,27.75L 34.9751,27.9233L 34.1999,28.5016C 33.7232,28.8527 33.3321,29.2594 33.0265,29.7217C 32.7209,30.184 32.4937,30.683 32.3448,31.2186C 32.1959,31.7542 32.1203,32.3152 32.1178,32.9015C 32.1154,33.4878 32.1785,34.0839 32.3073,34.6897L 32.7064,36.0732L 33.3233,37.4329L 33.7336,38.3148L 34.3565,39.3987L 35.3612,40.8958L 36.5256,42.4299L 37.5121,43.598L 38.452,44.6C 38.9269,45.1322 39.4357,45.5981 39.9782,45.9975C 40.5208,46.3969 41.0788,46.7171 41.6523,46.9581C 42.2258,47.1991 42.8059,47.3547 43.3926,47.4249C 43.9793,47.4951 44.5529,47.4706 45.1134,47.3515L 46.125,47.0266L 47.0749,46.4726L 47.8598,45.8793C 48.0264,45.7513 48.1434,45.5923 48.2107,45.4025C 48.2781,45.2127 48.2912,45.0209 48.25,44.8272L 48.0754,44.4314 Z
```

That's got Z in it - what does Z do?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, finally found it.  It's called "Stream Geometry mini language".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax